# Configuring SSL issue

Tags: ssl, tomcat

I have configured SSL on tomcat and can see that https access to the webapplication deployed on tomcat is working without any error.

However in the server manager, when i check the certificates and trusted certificates, it shows:

Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]-*default*-UNDEFINED
Certificate information cannot be obtained from this connector at runtime

and

Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]-*default*
No trusted certificates are configured for this virtual host

Clicking on Re-read TLS configuration files returns:
OK - Reloaded TLS configuration for all TLS virtual hosts

Any idea why the above info is returned

configured SSL but getting the above warnings in certificate chain and certificate